# Rinkeby faucet showed that transaction had completed but still no funds

Tags: metamask, rinkeby, faucets

I created a tweet and used the tweet link to request ether on from the rinkeby faucet and it showed that green alert mentioning that I had succeeded in requesting ether.

I selected the 3 ETH/8 hours option.

However I still don't have any ether showing on my MetaMask rinekby network.

I even checked that my wallet address was shown in the list of recipients.

Here's proof that rinkeby says it worked. The highlight address is mine.[image]

This is my first time requesting ether from rinkeby faucet. Is there something I've missed?

Comment: Sometimes the faucet stops working, either wait, or try contacting them by github issue or a social network.

Comment: Yes, I tried again later that evening and it worked...